# Is the Tukey order well-founded

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ultrafilters

Consider the Tukey order restricted to directed orders of the form $(U,\supseteq)$, where $U$ is an ultrafilter on $\omega$. It is defined as follows:

For two ultrafilters $U,W$ on $\omega$, we say that $U\leq_T W$ if there is a function $f:W\rightarrow U$ which is cofinal. Namely, for every cofinal set/base $B\subseteq W$ (i.e. $\forall a\in W\exists b\in B$ s.t. $b\subseteq a$), $f''B\subseteq U$ is cofinal (See [Dobrinen/Todorcevic](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4153) for more details).

We define $$U\equiv_T W \iff U\leq_T W\wedge W\leq_T U$$

and

$$U<_TW \iff U\leq_T W\wedge U\not\equiv_T W.$$

Q. Is it well-founded? Is it consistently well-founded?

Comment: Please tell me I’m not the only one who misread it as the ‘Turkey order’ and thought it appropriate for the holidays.

Comment: @AlecRhea Google definitely agrees with you, it is so annoying to look up papers on the matter.

Comment: Consistently with ZF all ultrafilters are principal. So in that case... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I always forget to say "in ZFC". I should be more careful knowing you are around...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll show that the Tukey order is consistently ill-founded. I suspect it is open whether it is consistently well-founded. As you are aware, the well-foundedness of the Tukey order is not known to be inconsistent, since it is a longstanding open problem whether it is consistent that there is just one Tukey equivalence class of ultrafilters (Isbell's problem); in this case, the Tukey order is well-founded.

To see that the Tukey order is consistently ill-founded, I'll assume CH plus $|P(\mathbb R)\cap L(\mathbb R)| = \aleph_1$. From this hypothesis one can construct a descending sequence in the Tukey order. Later I'll sketch how to remove the hypothesis that $|P(\mathbb R)\cap L(\mathbb R)| = \aleph_1$ and prove the ill-foundedness of the Tukey order from CH alone.

First, there is a countable sequence $\langle U_n\rangle_{n < \omega}$ that is $L(\mathbb R)$-generic for the full support product $\mathbb P$ of $P(\omega)/\text{Fin}$ forcings. This is because this forcing is countably closed and has only $\aleph_1$ dense subsets that belong to $L(\mathbb R)$.

Each $U_n$ is a selective ultrafilter, and by mutual genericity, $U_n$ is not in $L(\mathbb R)[\langle U_m\rangle_{m \neq n}]$. Let $$W_n = U_0\text{-}\lim_{k\in \omega}\bigotimes_{m < k}U_{n+m}$$ Then $W_0 \geq_{\text{RK}} W_1 \geq_{\text{RK}} W_2\geq _{\text{RK}}\cdots$, and I claim that for all $n\geq 1$, $W_n \not \leq_T W_{n+1}$. In fact, $U_n\not\leq_T  W_{n+1}$ whereas $U_n\leq_{\text{RK}} W_n$. The reason is that $W_{n+1}$ is basically generated (by Dobrinen-Todorcevic's Theorem 16 from "Tukey types of ultrafilters"). Therefore any ultrafilter below $W_{n+1}$ in the Tukey order belongs to $L(\mathbb R)[W_{n+1}]$ by Raghavan-Todorcevic's Theorem 17 from "Cofinal types of ultrafilters."
But $L(\mathbb R)[W_{n+1}]\subseteq L(\mathbb R)[U_0,\langle U_m\rangle_{m \neq n}]$, so $U_n\notin L(\mathbb R)[W_{n+1}]$ (here we need that $n\geq 1$), and hence $U_n\not\leq_T W_{n+1}$.

With more care one can construct a decreasing sequence assuming CH alone. In fact, the same argument can be employed, forcing instead over $L_\alpha(\mathbb R)$ where $\alpha$ is the least ordinal such that $L_\alpha(\mathbb R)$ satisfies the first 10,000 axioms of $\text{ZF}$. Note that $L_\alpha(\mathbb R)$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$, so there is an $L_\alpha(\mathbb R)$-generic filter on $\mathbb P$. This yields a sequence of ultrafilters $U_n$, and the argument above shows that the associated ultrafilters $W_n$ form a Tukey descending sequence.

EDIT: Now that I have spent an hour on this proof, I see that Raghavan-Shelah have done much better by proving that under $\text{MA}(\sigma\text{-centered})$, there is an order embedding from $P(\omega)/\text{Fin}$ into the Tukey order on p-points.

Comment: Thanks Gabe! For some reason I remembered the result of Raghavan-Shelah differently (that they embedded $[\omega]^{<\omega}$). BTW, why did you force over $L(\mathbb{R})$? What if you just force over any ground model? This is the direction I was going for, but missed your nice definition of the $W_n$’s.

Comment: I wanted to prove from CH that the ultrafilters exist, so I didn't really force, I constructed the generic from CH.

Comment: It turns out that the construction using the $P(\omega)/fin$ is more suitable for the application I have in mind than the one obtained in Raghavan-Shelah. Thanks for that!

Comment: Glad to hear it's of some use!

Comment: Raghavan-Shelah:[shelah.logic.at:1058](https://shelah.logic.at/papers/1058/),
[arXiv:1411.0084](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0084),
[DOI:10.1090/tran/6943](https://doi.org/10.1090/tran/6943), [MR: 3624416](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3624416)